# PHP Create array with placeholders

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I am creating an array in php using data retrieved from my stored procedure:

```
            <root>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>6</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTotal>1774</grandTotal>
                <totalBooks>1288</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>486</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>7</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTotal>1488</grandTotal>
                <totalBooks>842</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>986</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>8</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTotal>253</grandTotal>
                <totalBooks>143</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>110</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
```

This data shows totals from months of the year. I need to create an array for the full year (all 12 months) even if there is no data.

I'm using a charts plugin that takes an array of data and displays it accordingly.

```
//DB pull data
$objDB = new DB;
$info = $objDB->setStoredProc('tuitionFetchStats')
     -> setParam("action", 'y2d')        
     -> execStoredProc()
     -> parseXML();  

$books = array(); 
$tuition = array(); 
$grandTotal = array(); 

foreach($info->dataSet as $data){

    $books[] = $data->totalBooks;
    $tuition[] = $data->tuitionTotal;
    $grandTotal[] = $data->grandTotal;

}
```

The above code is how I am getting my data but as you can see, my array would start at month but the plugin I'm using starts at January. In this case, the columns would all be off.

I need to create the array in a way where if month 1 is missing, the first value in the array is just empty but its there as a placeholder for the month of January.

What would be the best way to do this?

You can see this demo which is similar to mine [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)

The part I',m having the issue with is the data contained in the series. Some of the months wont have data right now but I still need the data to align up for data that does exist.

Comment: js fiddle link is broken

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the month currently used is either the first or the next after the previous and fill it up if needed (as well as in the end)

```
$last = 0;
foreach($info->dataSet as $data){
    $month = $data->reimbursementMonth;
    while ($month > ($last+1)) {
        $books[] = 0;
        $tuition[] = 0;
        $grandTotal[] = 0;
        $last++;
    }

    $books[] = $data->totalBooks;
    $tuition[] = $data->tuitionTotal;
    $grandTotal[] = $data->grandTotal;
    $last = $month;

}
while ($last < 12) {
    $books[] = 0;
    $tuition[] = 0;
    $grandTotal[] = 0;
    $last++;
}
```